# WebAPI: GET method called instead of POST method

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I've encountered a strange problem tonight. I tried to implement POST method in my REST API, but the GET is called instead. I can see also a 301 Moved Permanently with Fiddler.

Here is my code, I tested it with Postman. It calls also GET method when I get it:

```
[Route("api/v1/shops/{shopId}/products/")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProducts(int shopId)
{
     ...
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

[Route("api/v1/shops/{shopId}/products/")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateProduct(int shopId, Product product)
{
    ...

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I've tried with different methods signatures, with hardcoded id but it failed:

```
[Route("api/v1/shops/1/products/")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateProduct(Product product)
```

**UPDATE**

I have also thie method who works before tonight...

```
[Route("api/v1/shops/")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateShop(Shop shop)
```

Comment: Show the raw request that hits the post action. Given that we cannot see what you get in postman

Comment: Also make sure that you enabled attribute routing. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()`

Comment: Yeah MapHttpAttributeRoutes is called. I think I found why, I removed the backslash in route and it works... weird. Maybe it's because I have a rewriting rule that remove trailing slash...

Comment: But do you know why it gave 301?